# Shopify, Services with Products

Tags: shopify, shopping-cart, variants

I am trying to figure out the best way to solve my problem below. The issue involves services (non-taxable) and products that are taxable.

My website offers CPR courses which is a service (non-taxable), along with the option to purchase the book which is taxable. So I set up the products as the CPR courses and the variants as, "yes" or "no" on purchasing the book.

If the user selects yes, how would I add an additional product to the cart when they check out?

The user can also buy the book by itself, so I set those up as products as well.

Is there another way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that. taxable is a variant level field so one variant can be taxable and the other not.

Your course products can have their own template and it would expand the list of variants so they are both shown. Your template would have to offer the option of adding both products to the cart. That could then be accomplished by using the [cart api](https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api#add-to-cart)